# Java Multithread. How to halt the threads and to free the launcher?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc, future, callable

I have this using: Spring MVC (Controller + Service + ThreadPoolTaskExecutor), Callable and Future.

```
@Controller
  launch-method   [invokes Service:launch-method and get result with Future]
  stop-method     [invokes Service:stop-method]

@Service [to launch async Tasks]
  launch-method   [Loop with threadPoolTaskExecutor.submit(callable)]
  stop-method     [threadPoolTaskExecutor.shutdown()]
```

The stop event flow that I have is:

1. User clicks a stop button and invokes a **Controller: stop-method**
2. The **Controller: stop-method** invokes the **Service: stop-method**
3. ¿? The **Service: stop-method** shutdown and notify **Controller: launch-method**

And I need to code the step 3, to notify to the **Controller: launch-method** that the process has finished.

I don't know why threadPoolTaskExecutor.shutdown() doesn't free the **Controller: launch-method**, which is waiting in: *result = future.get();* and no Exception is raised.

```
try {
    for (Future<String> future : sentResult) {
       result = future.get();
       ...
    }
} catch (ExecutionException e) {...}
  catch (InterruptedException e) {...}
  catch (CancellationException e) {...}
  catch (Exception e) {...}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

you can design in `observer-observable` pattern. Where Controller will be `Observer` and service will be `Observable`. And once service has been stopped it will trigger `setChanged();
and notifyObservers();` to notify controller that it is done.

Comment: Thanks, but the communication between Controller and Service is established with the Future object which is waiting the result of the Service method